# How to render Ember component on same line

Tags: ember.js

This Ember [template code](https://github.com/chroaster/super-rentals/blob/master/app/templates/components/rental-listing.hbs)...

```
<div class="detail bedrooms">
  <span>Number of bedrooms:</span> {{rental.bedrooms}}
</div>
<div class="detail temperature">
  <span>Current Temperature:</span> {{city-temperature location=rental.city}}
</div>
```

...results in this rendering...
[image: screenshot of component text on wrong line]

How could one get the "25C" text to render on the same line as "Current Temperature" in the same way that "San Francisco" is on the same line as "Location"?

I have tried getting the city-temperature component to return only text, but (secondary question here) is it even possible for a component to return only text if the text is from a remote ajax request since the promise seems to need a DOM element to append to?

This Ember app is available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/chroaster/super-rentals). It's a modified version of the official Ember.js tutorial app with this "Current Temperature" detail added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that; `city-temperature` is a component; and by default ember components is assigned `div` as their tags. Due to this; the content of `city-temperature` starts at a new line.

What can you do? Play with `css` and make sure `div` tag of `city-temperature` does not start at a new line; but instead floating right within the owner div. The second option is making `city-temperature` component tagless; so that it does not start at a new line. To achieve that; you can just declare:

```
tagName: ''
```

within `city-temperature.js`. You can see the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/45483d9adfce9d440c5f7b3a8e5d46f1?openFiles=components.city-temperature.js%2Ctemplates.components.city-temperature.hbs) to see the second option I mentioned.

After reading your comments; I have forked your repository and made minor modifications to achieve what you want. You can check my [repository](https://github.com/feanor07/super-rentals) and my corresponding [commit](https://github.com/feanor07/super-rentals/commit/719b2e04255ebb4c4bffa9f65c2ba23286cbf626) to see what I changed.

Basically; I really did not like the idea that `weather` service is returning a DOM element. I have changed it to return an instance of ember promise (I mean `Ember.RSVP.Promise`). Within `city-temperature.js` I just set a retrieved weather value from `weather` service and set it to the component instead of making DOM modification. Finally; I modified `city-temperature.hbs` to render `weatherValue` and added a simple css item in order to prevent `weather-container` div to insert a new line break.

I am not sure; whether you will like my solution or not; but I guess you will retrieve the visual appearance you want. You can always rely on promises for async tasks; you do not need to create DOM elements and pass them around to components and append them to somewhere within DOM tree of the corresponding component. I believe one of the reasons we are making use of a framework like `Ember` is to prevent such DOM modifications. Best regards.

Comment: When all I do is add `tagName: ''` to `components/city-temperature.js`, the component doesn't render at all and I get this error in the console:

    Assertion Failed: You cannot access this.$() on a component with `tagName: ''` specified.

But when I use `tagName: 'span'`, [it works, though it throws off the vertical spacing a bit](https://i.imgur.com/V8F22AQ.png).

Comment: @Chroaster sorry; i did not check the source code you have provided. I have just noticed you are accessing `this.$` within [js file](https://github.com/chroaster/super-rentals/blob/master/app/components/city-temperature.js). so you can apply as @ykaragol suggested; but it seems you have an extra space. let me clone your repository and play with it a little bit.

Comment: this should probably just be a helper, not a component

Comment: @alptugd Thank you for this! I learned a lot by reading your changes. I suspected there was a way to do it with promises but my unfamiliarity with the framework was blinding me. I used all your changes except for one. I didn't need any CSS after I changed ...
`<div class="weather-container">{{weatherValue}}</div>`
...to this...
`{{weatherValue}}`
...in `templates/components/city-temperature.hbs`.

Such a relief to finally get the result I wanted without passing the DOM element around. So, the tutorial probably only does that because it had to work with Google's Map API, right?

Comment: @runspired I think you are right. I did wonder if a component was overkill for basically just getting a single string. I will try to convert it to a helper as my next experiment. Thanks.

Comment: @runspired I agree with you; it should probably better be a helper.

Comment: @runspired
So, I attempted to convert this to a helper but I'm not sure how to make the helper return the result of the promise. If you get a chance, could you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185507/ember-helper-that-returns-the-resolved-value-of-a-promise)?

Answer (score 2):

An ember component adds a `div` by default. If you don't want to add this `div` tag, you need to set `tagName` to an empty string. 
That's called *tagless component*.

Further, for your case, you can give a `tagName='span'` so you will not need a `span` in your template.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ['weather-container'],
  weather: Ember.inject.service(),
  //rest of your code...
});
```

Comment: When I add `tagName: 'span'` and `classNames: ['weather-container']`, and then remove the `<span class="weather-container"></span>` from `templates/city-temperature.hbs`, the component doesn't render and there is no error message in the console. But I do get [this result](https://i.imgur.com/V8F22AQ.png) if I leave the span in the template.

Comment: That should be another thing. Have a look at @alptugd's new comments.